# Monitoring Azure Storage using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-java-sdk

I was monitoring microsoft.compute using a REST API Client and I was hoping that I could do the same for microsoft.storage. But unfortunately I get an error response while trying to do so

```
{
"code": "ResourceNotSupported",
"message": "Resource provider not supported: microsoft.storage"
}
```

The Rest API call I make is something similar to this

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/metricdefinitions?api-version=2016-03-01
```

Is there any way to get storage metrics from a REST API client?

Comment: As reference, you can refer to the other offical tutorial to know how to enable & view the metrics data for storage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/enabling-storage-metrics-and-viewing-metrics-data.

Comment: https://sedeks.blogspot.com/2019/09/how-to-get-azure-storage-metrics.html this link has this info

Answer (score 1):

Storage metrics are stored in a table called $MetricsTransactionsBlob. You will need to use the data plane APIs described in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/about-storage-analytics-metrics).

Simply you will need to access and query the table at `https://<accountname>.table.core.windows.net/Tables("$MetricsTransactionsBlob")`

Answer (score 0):

There is no Azure Insights for Azure storage.  You can use Storage analytics to get at the monitoring data that's stored in associated Table storage of the monitored account, but this will fail for Blob and Premium storage accounts.  This is a big oversight from the Azure API perspective.  For Standard Azure storage, you can get at the metric tables via the link that @Sercan provided.

If you're trying to monitor utilization of your VM disks on Premium or Blob accounts, you can use Physical Disk performance counters on the actual VMs to measure the throughput, IO requests, etc.  This is what we advise our [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com) users do when they have this need.